# d3.js Grouped Box plot

Tags: d3.js, boxplot

I would like to ask that is it possible to plot grouped box plots by D3.js like [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtazN.png) from Plotly?  So far, I didn't see any example on the internet yet.

Thanks in advance.

---

4th UPDATE: [SOLVED on 3/3/2016]

[image: Boxplot]

Boxplot grouped by dates at x axis and colored according to grouping on respective dates.

Solution is as below:

```
var state = svg1.selectAll(".state2")
  .data(dataset2)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "state")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" +  x0(d.Date)  + ",0)"; } );


state.selectAll(".box")
      .data(function(d) { return d.Data; })
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" +  x_1(d.group)  + ",0)"; } )
      .call(boxplot);
```

---

3rd UPDATE:

Done modifying data format. 
Issue: Boxplot for both dates are the same.

---

2nd UPDATE: 
Managed to group the Box plots but facing difficulties in formatting data into groups. [plunker version 9](https://plnkr.co/edit/naP7XXkNcaxSJRmpTQv5?p=preview)

---

UPDATE: 
I am trying to change the first chart (Grouped Bar chart) to Grouped Boxplot. Hit error on line 140 at index.html. [plunker version 1](https://plnkr.co/edit/naP7XXkNcaxSJRmpTQv5?p=preview).

```js
state.selectAll(".box")    
  .data(function(d) { return d.data; })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" +  x_1(d)  + "," + margin.top + ")"; } )
  .call(boxplot.width(x0.rangeBand()));  //This line
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's doable, here is an example : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502.

The main idea here is just to use svg `rect` `path` and `circle` to achieve the box and whisker style.

If you are will to use `nvd3`, there is a built-in boxPlot graph ([example](https://github.com/nvd3-community/nvd3/blob/gh-pages/examples/boxPlot.html))

Comment: Thank you for the examples but what I am looking for is Grouped boxplot. I have tried nvd3 but it does not support grouping for box plot. 
(Documentation: https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#boxPlotChart)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #chartdiv {
          width: 100%;
          height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="chartdiv"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

    <!-- Chart code -->
    <script>
        am4core.ready(function() {

        // Themes begin
        am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
        // Themes end

        var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
        chart.paddingRight = 20;

        chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";

        var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
        dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 40;
        dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;

        var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
        valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;

        var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.CandlestickSeries());
        series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
        series.dataFields.valueY = "close";
        series.dataFields.openValueY = "open";
        series.dataFields.lowValueY = "low";
        series.dataFields.highValueY = "high";
        series.simplifiedProcessing = true;
        series.tooltipText = "Open:${openValueY.value}\nLow:${lowValueY.value}\nHigh:${highValueY.value}\nClose:${valueY.value}\nMediana:{mediana}";
        series.riseFromOpenState = undefined;
        series.dropFromOpenState = undefined;

        chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

        var medianaSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.StepLineSeries());
        medianaSeries.noRisers = true;
        medianaSeries.startLocation = 0.1;
        medianaSeries.endLocation = 0.9;
        medianaSeries.dataFields.valueY = "mediana";
        medianaSeries.dataFields.dateX = "date";
        medianaSeries.strokeWidth = 2;
        medianaSeries.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");


        var topSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.StepLineSeries());
        topSeries.noRisers = true;
        topSeries.startLocation = 0.2;
        topSeries.endLocation = 0.8;
        topSeries.dataFields.valueY = "high";
        topSeries.dataFields.dateX = "date";
        topSeries.stroke = chart.colors.getIndex(0);
        topSeries.strokeWidth = 2;

        var bottomSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.StepLineSeries());
        bottomSeries.noRisers = true;
        bottomSeries.startLocation = 0.2;
        bottomSeries.endLocation = 0.8;
        bottomSeries.dataFields.valueY = "low";
        bottomSeries.dataFields.dateX = "date";
        bottomSeries.stroke = chart.colors.getIndex(0);
        bottomSeries.strokeWidth = 2;


        chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();

        chart.data = [ {
            "date": "2019-08-01",
            "open": 132.3,
            "high": 136.96,
            "low": 131.15,
            "close": 136.49
          }, {
            "date": "2019-08-02",
            "open": 135.26,
            "high": 135.95,
            "low": 131.50,
            "close": 131.85
          }, {
            "date": "2019-08-03",
            "open": 129.90,
            "high": 133.27,
            "low": 128.30,
            "close": 132.25
          }, {
            "date": "2019-08-04",
            "open": 132.94,
            "high": 136.24,
            "low": 132.63,
            "close": 135.03
          }, {
            "date": "2019-08-05",
            "open": 136.76,
            "high": 137.86,
            "low": 132.00,
            "close": 134.01
          }, {
            "date": "2019-08-06",
            "open": 131.11,
            "high": 133.00,
            "low": 125.09,
            "close": 126.39
          }, {
            "date": "2019-08-07",
            "open": 130.11,
            "high": 133.00,
            "low": 125.09,
            "close": 127.39
          }, {
            "date": "2019-08-08",
            "open": 125.11,
            "high": 126.00,
            "low": 121.09,
            "close": 122.39
          }, {
            "date": "2019-08-09",
            "open": 131.11,
            "high": 133.00,
            "low": 122.09,
            "close": 124.39
          }];

          addMediana();

          function addMediana(){
            for(var i = 0; i < chart.data.length; i++){
                var dataItem = chart.data[i];
                dataItem.mediana = Number(dataItem.low) + (Number(dataItem.high) - Number(dataItem.low)) / 2;
            }
          }

        }); // end am4core.ready()
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```